# Dart: The type of function literal can't be inferred because the literal has a block as its body

Tags: dart, flutter

I am developing an app using flutter.

In the below code I am getting this warning.

> The type of function literal can't be inferred because the literal has a block  as its body.

```
var onSelectSunriseNotification = () {
  print('Sunrise Notification clicked');
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing `var` with `void` will remove that warning. [This issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32843) is similar to yours.

```
void onSelectSunriseNotification = () {
    print('Sunrise Notification clicked');
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Using this inside another function also removes the warning:

```dart
void main() {
  var onSelectSunriseNotification = () {
    print('Sunrise Notification clicked');
  };
}
```